# Rails: Datetime params are empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, parameters

In my post view, I have a `_form` with a `title` and `releaseDate` parameter.

In my controller I get the value from `params[:post][:title]`, but the `params[:post][:releaseDate]` is empty.

**post _form**

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :releaseDate %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :releaseDate %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller**

```
def create
    @title = params[:post][:title]
    @date = params[:post][:releaseDate]

    @post = Post.new(title: @title, releaseDate: @date)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

(I am not using `@post = Post.new(params[:post])` because I want to do something with the `title` and `releaseDate` in the controller.)

**post.rb (model)**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :releaseDate, :title, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Any suggestions on how I can get the datetime value from the form and into my controller?

Comment: what is the type of `releaseDate` field in you model?

Comment: I added the model now. In the migration file it is `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

`releaseDate` is not rails convention, try to rename field to `release_date`. Maybe this will help.

To proof this concept you can use so called virtual attributes: add release_date getter and setter to model like this (note that logs can help you to narrow down the problem) :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :releaseDate, :title, :user_id
  belongs_to :user

  def release_date
    date = read_attribute('releaseDate')
    logger.debug("READ DATE IS #{date} aND CLASS IS #{date.class}") # see this in rails server logs 
  end

  def release_date=(date)
    logger.debug("WRITE DATE IS #{date} aND CLASS IS #{date.class}") # see this in rails server logs 
    write_attribute('releaseDate', date)
  end
end
```

And in view replace all `releaseDate` with `release_date`